# How to get count of a specific digit in android

Tags: java, android

I want to create an android app witch converts units and i need to show big numbers
I need to count zero digits in my app
How is that possible?

Thanks for your help

Comment: what are the approaches you tried so far?

Comment: You must provide some code of what you have tried. There are many many ways to solve problems like these

Comment: I want a simple way that you may have experienced

Comment: Please show us your code so far.

Comment: Unfortunately your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks!

Comment: Respectively: your question boils down to "somebody please please help me with this". But we do not regard such requests as *questions* in the scope of this site. Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) carefully to understand why that is. Then consider to either delete this question and putting up a new, more precise question within the scope of this community. Alternatively, you could [edit], rework and improve this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
int x = your_integer;
        String strNum = "" + x;
        int c = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < strNum.length(); i++) {
            if (strNum.charAt(i) == '0') {
                c++;
            }
        }
```